# Titanium get Current tabgroup

Tags: tabs, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

is there any method like `Ti.UI.CurrentWindow` that return current tabgroup like `Ti.UI.CurrentTabGroup`?

I want to add a tab to the current tabgroup in one of the application tabs?

Comment: Note that those aren't methods, they're properties. Also, the casing is wrong. Should be: `Ti.UI.currentWindow`. Note that there is a property `Ti.UI.currentTab`, but there is no `Ti.UI.currentTabGroup`.

Answer (score 5):

No there isn't... Just store your tab group as a global variable and you should be fine